# Is it okay to collect my Schengen visa one month after applying?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm applying for a Schengen Visa and it needs two weeks to be issued, during those week I will be traveling to another country. Is it OK to pick up my passport with the Visa issued after 1 month?

Comment: Where are you located and from which embassy did you get your visa from?

Comment: Ask organization where you will get your visa

Comment: Jordan, Hungary but I'm gonna be in the US when it's issued.

Comment: How will you be traveling if your passport is in another country ?

Comment: I have two passports mate, I'm travelling on the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the embassy (or agency) that is processing your visa.  They may require you to pick it up within a few days - or they may offer to courier it to you.

The rules will differ based on the embassy / agency used; thus you need to ask.

If your concern is the validity of the visa, then it is valid from the dates listed on the visa; which should be inline with the dates you mentioned in your itinerary when you applied.